Places API function findCurrentPlace() limits my app min SDK to 26
I tried adding the users current location to the google map I had using google places api, and while it worked, I noticed that under api level 26 it gave an error, after elaborating I found that the error happens because the code requires Java 8.0. After some debugging I found that the line: Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResponse = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request); was the thing that was causing the issue. The code never reaches the After find Current Place log.
Here is my entire fragments java component:
package com.example.restaurantapp;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceResponse;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link GmapsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class GmapsFragment extends Fragment
{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public GmapsFragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment GmapsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static GmapsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2)
    {
        GmapsFragment fragment = new GmapsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
        {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmaps, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapContainer);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap)
            {
                LatLng def = new LatLng(0, 0);
                LatLng bs = new LatLng(31.25150448, 34.79455390);
                //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(def).title("Sydney"));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(def));
                CameraPosition cam = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(bs).zoom(10).build();
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cam));
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);}
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        String apiKey = BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY;
        Places.initializeWithNewPlacesApiEnabled(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
        setCurrentLocation();

        return view;
    }

    public void setCurrentLocation()
    {
        List<Place.Field> placeFields = Collections.singletonList(Place.Field.DISPLAY_NAME);
        Log.d("PlacesDebug", "Before FindCurrentPlaceRequest");
        FindCurrentPlaceRequest request = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);
        Log.d("PlacesDebug", "After FindCurrentPlaceRequest");
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(requireContext());
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.d("PlacesDebug", "Before findCurrentPlace");
            Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResponse = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);
            Log.d("PlacesDebug", "After findCurrentPlace");
            placeResponse.addOnCompleteListener(task ->
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods())
                    {
                        Log.i("CurrentLocation", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %f", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Exception exception = task.getException();
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        Log.e("NotFound", "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // A local method to request required permissions;
            // See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
            //regetLocationPermission();
        }

    }
}

I would prefer to at least attempt to use minSDK 24, despite the fact that I recognize that my app may not be compatible with it when I complete it. I would prefer not to cut any corners, currently my options are either making minSDK 26, or backporting. Any help is appreciated.
